# Discretization of Unit Vector in 3D

Tags: euclidean-geometry, vectors, 3d

I cant think of a thing that I think is supposed to be easy... =/
Im glad if you could help me.

Im working with a regular discretization of a 3d euclidean space. Cubic cells. Then, after a black-box-like process, I have a unit vector that is related to a specific cell. I know that it must be pointing to any of the 26 neighbors (9 in upper and bottom level, 8 in the same). But, which cell is it pointing?

In 2D, using square cells, was easy to develop a code to do that... but I cant think how it should be in 3D.

Im solving a BVP of a 3D Elliptic PDE with finite difference scheme. After I solve it, since in the specific PDE Im using I have a property of just having on local minimum, which is the global minimum, I wanna trace a path from a random point, going along gradient descendant lines, until the global minimum. So, the discretization arises because of FDS, and my vector field are just the inverse of the gradient field (ie, gradient descendant) of my solved BVP/PDE.

Some formalities that I forgot and DavidK pointed out.

Let 
$$v \in R^3, \quad with \quad ||v||=1$$
be a vector.

Also, consider a regular discretization of a region of R^3, with
$$ \Delta_x = \Delta_y = \Delta_z = 1  $$
Ie, cubic cells, with 0=(0,0,0) being its initial point.

Example1:
Lets consider one cubic-cell inside the domain. Without loss of generalization, let it be the closest one to the origin, ie, since the one centered at (0.5,0.5,0.5) is in the border, lets choose the one centered at (1.5,1.5,1.5).

If v=(1,0,0), it is pointing to the cell centered in (2.5,1.5,1.5).

If v=(2^(1/2),-2^(1/2),0), it is pointing to the cell centered in (2.5,0.5,1.5).

Comment: It's pointing to the cell where it's pointing; what would help someone answer this is to know exactly in what form is the information you have about the vector, and how you want the answer "which cell" to be described. Perhaps a couple of examples of a "unit vector" would help; it also might help to see an explanation of how this can be done in 2D (because that will help show what format of input to the process you might have, and how you might want the output to be formatted).

Comment: @DavidK,  I hope I could do what you asked me.

Comment: OK, problem seems a lot clearer now; I have put some thoughts about it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a few things that might be useful to do.

If you can easily compute the reversed gradient vector at the center of your
current cell, it might not point directly to the center of an adjacent cell,
so you might want to try to find which cell's center
it most "nearly" points toward.

Suppose you are currently "at" the cell centered at $(x,y,z)$
and the reversed gradient vector at $(x,y,z)$, scaled to a unit vector, 
is $\hat v = (\hat v_x, \hat v_y, \hat v_z).$

**One approach** might be to predefine a set of $26$ unit vectors,
each of which points directly at the center of a neighboring cell.
The examples you gave, $(1,0,0)$ and 
$\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac1{\sqrt2},0\right)$,
are two such vectors, pointing to $(x+1,y,z)$ and $(x+1,y-1,z)$,
respectively;
$\left(\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)$
is such a vector pointing to $(x+1,y+1,z+1)$.
In fact, you can start with the $26$ center-to-center vectors
of the form $w = (w_x,w_y,w_z)$ with $w_x,w_y,w_z \in \{-1,0,1\}$
(excluding the vector $(0,0,0)$)
and scale each one appropriately 
(divide the coordinates by $\sqrt2$ or $\sqrt3$).

Out of those $26$ vectors, the vector $\hat w$ that produces the largest value
of $\hat v \cdot \hat w$ is the one "closest" to $\hat v$ 
(measured by the angle between the vectors). 
You could choose that vector as the one pointing to the
same cell as $\hat v$, and by "unscaling" the vector back to the vector
$w = (w_x,w_y,w_z)$ in the same direction whose coordinates
are all in the set $\{-1,0,1\}$,
you can say that $\hat v$ is pointing at the cell $(x+w_x, y+w_y, z+w_z)$.

You don't actually need to take $26$ dot products every time, because simply
checking the signs (positive or negative) of $\hat v_x,$ $\hat v_y,$ 
and $\hat v_z$ you can eliminate all but seven of the possible $\hat w$ vectors.
You can narrow this down even further by considering whether
$|v_x|>|v_y|$ and so forth, but that may be overkill.

[**Edit:** I should emphasize that there can be *two* vectors in each of the $26$ directions. For example, the vector from $(x,y,z)$ to $(x+1,y-1,z)$ is
$w=(1,-1,0)$, but in order to decide whether to go in that direction you take
a dot product with the unit vector 
$\hat w=\frac{w}{\|w\|}=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac1{\sqrt2},0\right)$
in the same direction.
If you take dot products with unequal vectors in the $26$ directions
then the results will be biased toward the longer vectors.
On the other hand, if you use the negative gradient $v$ instead of the
unit vector $\hat v$ in all the dot products, they will all be scaled by
the same factor, $\|v\|$, so no bias is introduced.
It is therefore not strictly necessary to compute $\hat v$
so that you can use it instead of $v$.]

[Another thought is that by traversing a suitably-constructed
decision tree whose decisions are
based on comparisons of coordinates of $v$ such as $v_x > k_1v_y$ or
$v_x + v_y > k_2v_z$, I think you can determine which of the dot products
would be greatest without actually having to compute any of them.
But this would likely be a lot of work on your part for little benefit.]

**A second possible approach** is: if $\hat v_x < -\frac12$ then set $w_x = -1$,
if $\hat v_x > \frac12$ then set $w_x = 1$, and otherwise set $w_x = 0$;
similarly use the values of $\hat v_y$ and $\hat v_z$ to set
$w_y$ and $w_z$; then say that $\hat v$ is pointing at the
cell centered at $(x+w_x, y+w_y, z+w_z)$.  What you would actually have
determined, however, is the cell in which the point
$(x+\hat v_x, y+\hat v_y, z+\hat v_z)$ lies.  Given a vector $\hat v$
in a completely random direction, I think this is more likely than the previous
method to end up "moving" you in the direction $(\pm1,0,0)$,
$(0,\pm1,0)$, or $(0, 0, \pm1)$. You may not want that.

**A third approach** is to determine which coordinate of $\hat v$
($\hat v_x$, $\hat v_y$, or $\hat v_z$), is the largest, and
scale $\hat v$ by a positive factor $a$ so that the absolute value of
that coordinate becomes $1$.
This puts the point $(x + a\hat v_x, y + a\hat v_y, z + a\hat v_z)$
on the surface of a $2\times2\times2$ cube centered at $(x,y,z)$;
use a technique similar to the one in the "second approach"
(if $a\hat v_x < -\frac12$ then set $w_x = -1$, etc.)
to decide which cell's center this point is closest to.

Actually, with the "third approach" you do not even need to scale
the reversed gradient to a unit vector first; you can scale it directly to a
vector whose largest coordinate has absolute value $1$ and proceed from there.

**The fourth approach** is not to try to find which cell the 
reversed gradient vector points to, 
but simply visit cells adjacent to the cell centered at $(x,y,z)$
and choose the one where the least value of the function is found.
This is a standard "hill-climbing" strategy (except going down to a
minimum rather that up to a maximum in this case).
You might or might not want to use the gradient to rule out directions
to search in; assuming the value in each cell has already been computed,
it is just a matter of visiting each one and choosing the best value.
(If you remember the *previous* cell in the search, you may be
able at least to skip cells adjacent to that cell, since if they were
better than your "current" location they would already have been selected.)

Comment: I think that the first approach, indeed, is the closest one to what I am searching for. Since second and third approach are based on Manhattan distance, although they will find (as I could understand that) the minimum, they will loose some "smoothness" of the path... The forth approach I think that also solve the problem, but as my advisor told me, isn't an "elegant way" to do that. I was thinking that I could (orthogonal) project v onto XY-plane, and use my old scheme for 2D... but that leave me with no clue about Z.

Comment: Out-of-topic, how can I put embedded latex, without creating new lines? Ie... $$?

Comment: I was doing some tests here... new conclusion. I think that approach 1 doesnt work. See this example:
$$v=(1/sqrt(5), -2/sqrt(5), 0)$$. It reaches $$3/sqrt(5)$$ when I took dot product with $$w=(1,-1,-1)$$, $$w=(1,-1,0)$$ and $$w=(1,-1,1)$$. That happens because z is zero in gradient, so just x-y components that matter. However, trying the third approach, that leads to just  $$w=(1,-1,0)$$, which is the right cell in this case.

Comment: For approach 1, the three vectors you want are $\hat w_1=\left(\frac1{\sqrt3},-\frac1{\sqrt3},-\frac1{\sqrt3}\right),$ $\hat w_2=\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac1{\sqrt2},0\right),$ and $\hat w_3=\left(\frac1{\sqrt3},-\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3}\right).$ That is, they all have to be unit vectors. That's because the dot product doesn't just give $\cos\theta$; it gives $\|v\|\|w\|\cos\theta$, so if you let some vectors be longer then the comparisons will be biased toward those vectors.

Comment: For your example, $\hat v=\left(\frac1{\sqrt5},-\frac2{\sqrt5},0\right),$ $\hat v\cdot\hat w_1 = \hat v\cdot\hat w_3 = \sqrt{\frac35},$ but $\hat v\cdot\hat w_2 = \frac3{\sqrt{10}}>\sqrt{\frac35},$ so $\hat w_2$ "wins"; but to actually get to the desired cell you use $w_2=(1,-1,0)$, that is, _not_ the unit vector but a vector that will actually reach the desired cell's center. That sounds a bit complicated but it's simply $\hat w$ to choose the direction and $w$ to actually get there, where $\hat w = \frac{w}{\|w\|}.$

Comment: Incidentally, your advisor and I have slightly different ideas of what's "elegant." Method 1 is more mathematically "pure", but at the cost of making computations that method 4 completely avoids. Method 4 is not what you asked for, and I only mentioned it because it has the elegance of simplicity and efficiency; but I am not your advisor, and you're better off trusting him/her than some stranger on the Internet.

Comment: Damn. Sorry. I should have payed attention to that... but due to personal problems, Im not in my best mind-fit. So, you solved my problem... THANKS! =]
(and I agree with you about method 4! )

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this?
Extend your unit vector $v$ to a ray from its origin $o$,
$r=o + \alpha v$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.
Now iterate over the $26$ neighboring cells, computing the closet
approach of $r$ to the center of each cell.
(I am assuming you know how to perform this computation. E.g, see
[Wikipedia's *Distance from a point to a line*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line).)
Select the cell with the minimum distance to the ray.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I think that would not be cost-effective, since I need to perform this thousands of times per second. 

If you dont mind, please, take a look at a diagram of what I did in 2D:
http://imgur.com/0wahE5Q

Comment: I think it is easy to perform this computation thousands of times per second, but I cannot demonstrate that definitively. Good luck!